# Webapi with entity framework - use customer JSON converter to serialized DbGeography not working

Tags: json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am using webapi with DbGeography spatial data and want to serialize to json.
By default, DbGeography serializes to null. So I implemented my own converter for it.
Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to work.

Basically, with the following code, my DbGeographyConverter.WriteJson method is never under debug and the Location property is serialized as null

Customer converter:

```
public class DbGeographyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        DbGeography contextObj = value as DbGeography;

        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("Lat");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, contextObj.Latitude);

        writer.WritePropertyName("Long");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, contextObj.Longitude);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        if (objectType == typeof(DbGeography))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Add convert in Global.ascx.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
             GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(
 new DbGeographyConverter()

}
```

Finally, apply converter to the data model class property

```
public DataModelClass1
{

[JsonConverter (typeof(DbGeographyConverter))]
    public DbGeography Location { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: "does not work" is kind of vague...

Comment: First thing to check: is the `Location` property loaded when loading `DataModelClass1`?

Answer (score 0):

First, since you're adding your custom converter to the `SerializerSettings.Converters` collection, you don't need to decorate your DataModelClass1's Location property with the JsonConverterAttribute- The JsonFormatter will run through the aforementioned collection until it finds the derived JsonConverter you added without the attribute.

Now back to your question- which browser are you testing this in and how? If I were to speculate, I'd say you're using either Chrome or Firefox with GET requests, both of which prioritize `application/xml` over `application/json` in the [accept header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) they send to the server. For that reason Web API will see that the browsers prefer XML over JSON and the JsonFormatter will never be touched, let alone your custom JsonConverter.

There are a few workarounds to this. On the browser side the easiest way is to make ajax GET requests with jQuery and [specify that you want JSON back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322984/differences-bettween-contenttype-and-datatype-in-jquery-ajax-function#14323012). On the server side, you can [remove application/xml from the SupportedMediaTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome#12487921).

Answer (score 0):

I spent quite awhile on this. You'd only use the **write** method if you wanted to change the default output format of the Json for DbGeography from this

```
"geography": {
  "coordinateSystemId": 4326,
  "wellKnownText": "POINT (77.6599502563474 12.9602302518557)"
}
```

to something else like "77.22, 12.8" - just a single string.

If you're looking to convert a string like that to DbGeography on **reading** Json from the request, the code below is what you're after

```
public class DbGeographyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert ( Type objectType )
    {
        return objectType.IsAssignableFrom( typeof( string ) );
    }

    public override object ReadJson ( JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer )
    {
        if ( reader.Value == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        return Parser.ToDbGeography( reader.Value.ToString() );
    }

    public override void WriteJson ( JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer )
    {
        // Base serialization is fine
        serializer.Serialize( writer, value );
    }
}
```

This is the code for the Converter if you're passing in a string value -  12,99
Which will be you're lat and lng

This sample application has the answer you're looking for.
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/HTML-ASPNET-Web-API-Bing-58c97f9f

The Converter code from this can be found here 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/SQLDatabase-Spatial-WebAPI-BingMaps/blob/master/SpatialTypesWithWebAPI/Models/DbGeographyConverter.cs