# How can I enter data from clintside using webservice in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, json, web-services

I am trying this :

this my javascript code :

```
    function insertVisitor() {
        var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/QuizEntry.asmx")%>'
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: pageUrl + "/insert_Visitor",
            data: "{'name':'" + $("#txtName").val() + "','phoneno':'" +
                  $("#txtPhone").val() + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccessCall,
            error: OnErrorCall
        });

        return false();
    }

    function OnSuccessCall(response) {
        window.open("about.html");
    }

    function OnErrorCall(response) {
        alert(response.status + " " + response.statusText);
    }

</script>
```

this the html :

```
<form action="" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <label>
                            please enter your Name :
                        </label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <input id="txtName" type="text" value="" placeholder="Name" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        please enter your Phone No :
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <input id="txtPhone" type="text" value="" placeholder="Phone No" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <!--<input id="btnEnter" type="button" style="background-image:~/images/pop_up/enter.png; height:40px; width:120px" />-->
                        <!--<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="enter" onClick="window.location='about.html'" />-->
                        <!--<a href="about.html" style="display: block">-->
                            <img src="images/pop_up/enter.png" width="120" height="40" alt="img" style="width: 120px;
                                height: 40px; position: relative; right: 0;" onclick="return insertVisitor()" />
                         <!--</a>-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
```

and this is the webservice code :

```
 [WebMethod]
public string insert_Visitor(string name, string phoneno)
{
    string returnvalue = "";
    if (name != "" && phoneno != "")
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert_Into_VisitorLog";
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", phoneno);

        Object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        if (obj != "0" || obj != "Unexpected error occurred!!")
        {
            returnvalue = Convert.ToString(obj);
        }
        else
        {
            returnvalue = Convert.ToString(obj);
        }
    }


    return returnvalue;
}
```

the problem that i am facing is getting an error like this

```
400 Bad Request
```

how to solve this please help

Answer (score 0):

The data part in jQuery is wrong

```
 data: "{'name':'" + $("#txtName").val() + "','phoneno':'" +
              $("#txtPhone").val() + "'}",
```

it should be

```
 data: {'name': $("#txtName").val()  ,'phoneno': $("#txtPhone").val() },
```

### Edit 1

Also as you are returning string from you service so `dataType` is also wrong in you jquery call.

[Differences between contentType and dataType in jQuery ajax function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322984/differences-bettween-contenttype-and-datatype-in-jquery-ajax-function)

### Edit 2

```
   var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/QuizEntry.asmx")%>'+"/insert_Visitor?name="+ $("#txtName").val()+"&phoneno="+ $("#txtPhone").val() ;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pageUrl,
        success: OnSuccessCall,
        error: OnErrorCall
    });
```

### Edit 3

Get more about error detail use the following

```
function OnErrorCall(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
{
   alert(xhr.responseText);
}
```

Comment: am I missing something ?

Comment: though it is right but you can also try this data in the url. by appending this values.

Comment: how can i do that can you let me know

Comment: and what should i return then ? can you tell me that

Comment: No you are returning string from your service is right. But in jQuery you are telling that you will get Json from the service. Just omit like i have done in my answer.

Comment: @Shekhar: no not happening sir

Comment: what you are getting in `xhr.responseText`