# JQuery Ajax request not sending through post variables

Tags: jquery

I have difficulties sending through post variables using the JQuery Ajax function, when changing type to GET is all works.

CODE

```
function loadAttributes() {
            var selectedValues = [];    
            var presentValues = [];    
            $('#attrplaceholder div').each(function(){
                if (typeof $(this).data('attrid') !== 'undefined')
                {
                    presentValues.push($(this).data('attrid'));
                } 
             });
            $("#categories :selected").each(function(){
                   selectedValues.push($(this).val()); 
            });



            jQuery.ajax({
               url: 'backend.php?r=products/setProductAttributes',
               type: "POST",
               dataType:"html",
                contentType: 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
               data: {ids: selectedValues,presentids: presentValues},
               success: function(json){
alert(json)
                        if(json!='[]'){
                            var obj = eval ("(" + json + ")"); 
                            if(obj.json !== 'undefined'){
                                    $.each(obj.json, function(k, v) {
                                        if(k==='views'){
                                            $("#attrplaceholder").append(v);
                                        }
                                        if(k==='rem'){
                                            var remvals = v.toString().split(",");
                                            for(i=0;i<remvals.length;i++){
                                                $("#attrgrp_"+remvals[i]).remove();
                                            }

                                        }
                                    });
                            }
                        }
               }
               });
            return false;
         }

        loadAttributes() 

        $("#categories").on("change",function(){
            loadAttributes() 
        });
```

Any pointers will be helpful, I tried to play with the contentTypes and still no luck

Comment: If you use Firebug or Chrome dev tools, can you inspect the network calls and see if your AJAX call has the data in the request payload?

Comment: Add an `error` callback function, and log `textStatus`

Comment: @DavidHoerster - The request payload sends the following data ids%5B%5D=6&ids%5B%5D=16&ids%5B%5D=13 , so the data is being send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

contentType is the format of data **you send to server side**.

In your case, you should set it to: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` or `application/json; charset=UTF-8` depending on what format your server side expects

or remove it completely because by default `contentType` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

[Differences between contentType and dataType in jQuery ajax function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322984/differences-bettween-contenttype-and-datatype-in-jquery-ajax-function)

Comment: Thanks, the application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 seemed to have fixed the problem, I never tried that one or used the default value for contentType by leaving the out the option