# React- TypeError - this.state.movies.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I'm working on a movie rental project called MoVid, which is in React and JavaScript. Here's my code:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Movies from "./components/movies";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <main className="container">
      <Movies></Movies>
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Movie.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { getMovies } from "../services/fakeMovieService";

class Movies extends Component {
    state = {};

    render() {
        return (
            <table className="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Genre</th>
                        <th>Stock</th>
                        <th>Rate</th>
                    </tr>
               </thead>
           <tbody>
               {this.state.movies.map(movie => (
                   <tr>
                       <td>{movie.title}</td>
                       <td>{movie.genre.name}</td>
                       <td>{movie.numberInStock}</td>
                       <td>{movie.dailyRentalRate}</td>
                   </tr>
               ))}
           </tbody>
         </table>
    );
  }
}

export default Movies;
```

fakeGenreService.js

```
export const genres = [
  { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
  { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471814", name: "Comedy" },
  { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471820", name: "Thriller" }
];

export function getGenres() {
  return genres.filter(g => g);
}
```

fakeMovieService.js

```
import * as genresAPI from "./fakeGenreService";

const movies = [
{
  _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471815",
  title: "Terminator",
  genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
  numberInStock: 6,
  dailyRentalRate: 2.5,
  publishDate: "2018-01-03T19:04:28.809Z"
},
{
  _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471816",
  title: "Die Hard",
  genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
  numberInStock: 5,
  dailyRentalRate: 2.5
},
{
  _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471817",
  title: "Get Out",
  genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471820", name: "Thriller" },
  numberInStock: 8,
  dailyRentalRate: 3.5
}];

export function getMovies() {
  return movies;
}

export function getMovie(id) {
  return movies.find(m => m._id === id);
}

export function saveMovie(movie) {
  let movieInDb = movies.find(m => m._id === movie._id) || {};
  movieInDb.name = movie.name;
  movieInDb.genre = genresAPI.genres.find(g => g._id === movie.genreId);
  movieInDb.numberInStock = movie.numberInStock;
  movieInDb.dailyRentalRate = movie.dailyRentalRate;

  if (!movieInDb._id) {
    movieInDb._id = Date.now();
    movies.push(movieInDb);
  }

  return movieInDb;
}

export function deleteMovie(id) {
  let movieInDb = movies.find(m => m._id === id);
  movies.splice(movies.indexOf(movieInDb), 1);
  return movieInDb;
}
```

I have looked at:

[React code throwing “TypeError: this.props.data.map is not a function”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074638/react-code-throwing-typeerror-this-props-data-map-is-not-a-function)

[React JS - Uncaught TypeError: this.props.data.map is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142361/react-js-uncaught-typeerror-this-props-data-map-is-not-a-function)

But they don't help.

The other 3 files of code is in [here](https://trello.com/b/YS2hteC8/code).
If you need more information or code, please ask me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add your code where you get the movies data and assign it the `this.state.movies`

Comment: @thelonglqd I added the link to Trello for the 3 other files.

Comment: In `Movie` component, you did not use `getMovies` any where ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and the error you got is `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

Firstly, you do not use `getMovies` anywhere, your movies data is not available in `Movies` component

Secondly, you should initialize movies as empty array.

Your `Movies` component code should look like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { getMovies } from "../services/fakeMovieService";

class Movies extends Component {
    state = { movies: [] };

    componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({ movies: getMovies() });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <table className="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Genre</th>
                        <th>Stock</th>
                        <th>Rate</th>
                    </tr>
               </thead>
           <tbody>
               {this.state.movies.map(movie => (
                   <tr>
                       <td>{movie.title}</td>
                       <td>{movie.genre.name}</td>
                       <td>{movie.numberInStock}</td>
                       <td>{movie.dailyRentalRate}</td>
                   </tr>
               ))}
           </tbody>
         </table>
    );
  }
}

export default Movies;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no movies in your state from the start. Initialise an array inside the constructor:

```
state = {
    movies: [],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

this.state.movies is not an array. It's undefined.

Comment: If this case, the error should be `can not read property map of undefined`, not `map is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

In `state` of `Movie Component`, you need to add `movies` array like

```
state = {
movies:[]
};
```

then update the movies state. After that, you can map the `movies` array like this

```
<tbody>
     {this.state.movies.map(movie => (
    <tr>
     <td>{movie.title}</td>
     <td>{movie.genre.name}</td>
     <td>{movie.numberInStock}</td>
     <td>{movie.dailyRentalRate}</td>
    </tr>
   ))}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the same project, looks like you were missing  brackets in value method paginate function:

```
const startIndex = (pageNumber-1) * pageSize;

return _(items)
   .slice(startIndex)
   .take(pageSize)
   .value();
```