# React : list.map is not a function with array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fetching data using axios as the following :

```
{
    "data": {
        "3": {
            "id": 4,
            "value": "FaAlgolia",
            "name": "zaefzaef",
            "profile_id": 4,
            "order": 9000,
            "created_at": "2021-05-17T20:25:03.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-05-17T20:25:03.000000Z",
            "url": "katon",
            "profile": {
                "id": 4,
                "username": "xxxxxxxxx",
                "bio": "zfzefzef",
                "preview": "ssss",
                "address": "zefzef",
                "country": "us",
                "p_color": "#ffffff",
                "s_color": null,
                "logo": "afffable",
                "showlogo": "null",
                "selectedOption": "option2",
                "url": "katon",
                "user_id": 2,
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": "2021-05-17T20:28:08.000000Z"
            }
        },
        "4": {
            "id": 5,
            "value": "FaAlipay",
            "name": "azdadzzad",
            "profile_id": 4,
            "order": 9000,
            "created_at": "2021-05-17T20:41:53.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-05-17T20:41:53.000000Z",
            "url": "katon",
            "profile": {
                "id": 4,
                "username": "xxxxxxxxx",
                "bio": "zfzefzef",
                "preview": "ssss",
                "address": "zefzef",
                "country": "us",
                "p_color": "#ffffff",
                "s_color": null,
                "logo": "afffable",
                "showlogo": "null",
                "selectedOption": "option2",
                "url": "katon",
                "user_id": 2,
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": "2021-05-17T20:28:08.000000Z"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In **React** :

```
  const [list, setList] = React.useState([]); 

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8000/api/social/profile/katon")
      .then((response) => {
       let test = (response.data.data)
        setList(test)
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
```

`console.log` of `test`
[image]

I know that I have a problem with the received array, I tried adding [] but none of that worked.

I searched [React code throwing “TypeError: this.props.data.map is not a function”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074638/react-code-throwing-typeerror-this-props-data-map-is-not-a-function) & [React JS - Uncaught TypeError: this.props.data.map is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142361/react-js-uncaught-typeerror-this-props-data-map-is-not-a-function) and didn't find my answer.

Comment: This is not an array, this is an object. Objects don't have a `.map()` method.

Comment: @VLAZ I tried putting `[response.data.data]` to get the array but didn't work.

Comment: if you only want the values of the data object and have no use of the keys (3,4) then you can use `let test = Object.values(response.data.data);`

Comment: There isn't any array in your response

Comment: @AbdullahRazzaki It worked ! Thank you very much. I was trying to put `[response.data.data]` and `Array.from` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `response.data.data` is an object and objects don't have .map functions. You will need to convert it to an Array.

If you only want the values of the data object and have no use of the keys (3,4) then you can use

```
let test = Object.values(response.data.data);
```