# how to get data from 'ImmutableMultiDict' in flask

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

I am learning how to use ajax and Flask ,so what I do is I send a ajax request and I receive the data as `post` request in my python file

`My html file contains this code`

```
var data = {"name":"John Doe","age":"21"};
$.ajax({
  url:'/post/data',
  datatype : "json",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data : JSON.stringify(data),
  success : function(result) {
    jQuery("#clash").html(result); 
  },error : function(result){
     console.log(result);
 }
});
```

And My python file contains :

```
@app.route('/post/data',methods=['GET','POST'])
def postdata():
  #do some
  data = str(request.args)
  json_dumps = json.dumps(data)
  return json_dumps
```

This gives me following data on the page

```
"ImmutableMultiDict([('{\"name\":\"John Doe\",\"age\":\"21\"}', u'')])"
```

And this is what my `request.query_string` looks `{%22name%22:%22John%20Doe%22,%22age%22:%2221%22}`

So how do I get the `name` and `age`. Please correct me If I am wrong anywhere.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `request.json.get('name')`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You don't actually need to get data from an `ImmutableMultiDict`. There are a couple of errors in what you have that are preventing you from just pulling the response as json data. First off, you have to slightly tweak the parameters of your ajax call. You should add in the call type as a `POST`. Furthermore, `datatype` should be spelt as `dataType`. Your new call should be:

```
var data = {"name":"John Doe","age":"21"};
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: '/post/data',
    dataType : 'json',
    data : JSON.stringify(data),
    success : function(result) {
      jQuery("#clash").html(result); 
    },error : function(result){
       console.log(result);
    }
});
```

The data is now actually being sent as a post request with the `json` type. On the Flask server, we can now read the data as son information as follows:

```
@app.route('/post/data',methods=['GET','POST'])
def postdata():
    jsonData = request.get_json()
    print jsonData['name']
    print jsonData['age']
    return "hello world" #or whatever you want to return
```

This will print `John Doe` and `21` successfully.

Let me know if this works for you or if you have any additional questions!

Edit: You can return success to the ajax call from flask as follows:

```
# include this import at the tomb
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/post/data',methods=['GET','POST'])
    def postdata():
        ...
        return jsonify(success=True, data=jsonData)
```

Comment: This method works fine.. data is recieved in python file as I needed but in ajax it returns to `error` function.

Comment: What are you returning from your function? I'll get you a solution. Basically, what do you want the function to return, and what do you want `#clash` to display?

Comment: Okay I got the point. I should return from my function as some data (Json ) to ajax so that It would receive in success or otherwise it would be in error only.. Thanks for your kind help

Comment: Yup, just added the proper way to do so in the answer.

Comment: The catch here is that you always need to specify `contentType` in ajax request apart from `dataType`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322984/differences-between-contenttype-and-datatype-in-jquery-ajax-function

Comment: I am getting the following error : TypeError: expected string or buffer

Answer (score 9):

Just call to_dict on the request.form object E.g., http://www.seanbehan.com/how-to-get-a-dict-from-flask-request-form/

Comment: this was the answer i needed.

Comment: if you are uploading files instead of using form, just change it to request.files.to_dict()

Answer (score 7):

I came to this page because I'm trying to send a form with AJAX, and I finally found a solution. And the solution is to skip JSON (hope this will help others on the same search):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: my_url,
    data: $("#formID").serialize(), //form containing name and age
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Then, on the Flask server:

```
app.route('/my_url', methods = [POST])
def some_function():
    name = request.form['name']
    age = request.form['age']
    # do what you want with these variables
    return 'You got it right'
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by adding the contentType as application/JSON  like so

```
data ={ 
              type:'POST',
              contentType:'application/json',
              otherData: 'foo'
           }
```

You can now access the data in the flask backend like so:

```
app.route('/my_url', methods = ["POST"])
def some_function():
    other_data = request.form['otherData']
    # do something
```

Note: I used vanilla JavaScript for this not jQuery

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
var data = {"name":"John Doe","age":"21"};
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: '/my_url',
    dataType : 'json',
    data : JSON.stringify(data),
    success : function(result) {
      jQuery("#clash").html(result); 
    },error : function(result){
       console.log(result);
    }
});
```

In flask App:
improt json

```
@app.route('/my_url',methods=['POST,GET'])  # 
def some_function():
    dataList=list(request.form)[0] # output is string ==> '{"name":"John Doe","age":"21"}'
    b=json.loads(dataList) # output is dictionary ==> {"name":"John Doe","age":"21"}
    print(b) #{"name":"John Doe","age":"21"}

    return 'OK'
```