# Ajax with asp.net aspx returns Undefined

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, undefined

I'm facing the following issue: Whenever I click on the `button`, the `alert` shows `undefined`.

**Web method:**

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string getTest()
    {
        return "testing success";
    }
```

**Ajax script**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getTest() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "main.aspx/getTest",
                data: "{}",
                datatype: "json",
                contenttype: "/application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (msg) {

                    alert(msg.d);

                },
                error: function (data) {
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: contenttype: "/application/json; charset=utf-8"  remove / from start of application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datatype` should be `dataType` and `contenttype` should be `contentType`. Also remove / from start of `"/application/json; charset=utf-8"`

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "main.aspx/getTest",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (msg) {

                alert(msg.d);

            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: Man u saved my day... been spending hours on this thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Remove these from your ajax call

```
datatype: "json",
contenttype: "/application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

More about these

[Differences between contentType and dataType in jQuery ajax function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322984/differences-between-contenttype-and-datatype-in-jquery-ajax-function)

[What is content-type and datatype in an AJAX request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701282/what-is-content-type-and-datatype-in-an-ajax-request)

You can find more details in the [**jQuery Ajax documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I did but am still getting Undefined.

Comment: try alert `alert(msg);` and see what r u getting?