# jQuery's AJAX is not posting data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to send the key and value pairs to a PHP file using jQuery's AJAX function, however the function is not sending the data.

The PHP code is in the same "Tester.php" file together with the HTML code as shown below:

```
<?php
if (array_key_exists("REQUEST_METHOD", $_SERVER) && $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST); // always empty, no clue why!
    echo "</pre>";
    exit();
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Tester.php", // the same file/page
                data: {
                    requestData: true,
                    message: "please print me!"
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    document.write("success!");
                    document.write(data);
                },
                error: function(xmlHttp) {
                    document.write("error!");
                    document.write(xmlHttp.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Testing...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This prints:

```
success!
Array
(
)
```

But the array printed should contain the "requestData: true" from the data passed to the $_POST array, but instead this array is empty. What have I done wrong? Thank you!

Comment: your html file and php code file are on same page or different ?

Comment: They're on the same page. It's all in one file

Comment: separate both of files and make sure you had place comma in data as @Rmidi Ayoub suggested.

Comment: @HirendrasinhS.Rathod The comma is not the problem as I just added that message line on stackoverflow to make the problem easier to identify, but I've fixed that now. Also the original problem was on 2 separate files and still did not work. I put all of the code inside 1 file just because I thought it would be easier to explain.

Comment: @Mayron review my working example.

Comment: @Mayron if still you facing issue then install firebug and check in console that acctually request has been executed and what data will send to request file.

Comment: What if you remove `document.write("success!");` on success callback? Also I don't think you need to ask PHP whether `REQUEST_METHOD" is set or no.

Comment: @Chay22 I only asked whether it was set because it originally was in the same file. But if you split it into 2 then it's not necessary.

Comment: @HirendrasinhS.Rathod I have firebug installed but it reports no errors. I'm wondering if it's a bug with PHP or something else.

Comment: @Mayron I didn't ask you to separate it., just suggested it's not necessary to do `array_key_exists("REQUEST_METHOD", $_SERVER)`. And I guessed it doesn't work because `write()` overwrites everything on a page load. Dunno...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html File (36516400.html)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>36516400</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../assets/js/script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    data:{
                        'requestData':true,
                        'message':"please print me!"
                    },
                    url:'responce.php',
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                    success:function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP file (responce.php)**

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    echo "<pre>";
?>
```

**Request in chrome console**

[image]

Comment: Weird, for me that also alerts an empty array.

Comment: please review image i had added, you got this formData block

Comment: Ah yes I am getting that. But it should be inside the $_POST array. Maybe I need to set the content type if it thinks it's a form.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322984/differences-between-contenttype-and-datatype-in-jquery-ajax-function

for more details on content type.

Comment: Cannot figure out why $_REQUEST or $_POST is empty but I can see this formData block. How do I print that so it can be returned to the ajax's success function?

Comment: should you try method:'POST' instead of type:'POST' once ?

Comment: please add (headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}) additionally.

Comment: I assume it's some weird bug where the code is fine but it's still failing. Tried both of those with no luck. It's definitely type: "POST".

Comment: I think it's a bug with my IDE phpStorm that I'm using. Will look into it :) Thanks for your help though.

Comment: i am also using phpStrom. had you try to encode your .php or .html with utf-8 or utf-8 without bom using notpade++. any way if you find solution inform us so if we got this kind of issue we can kick out it.

Comment: It was just a matter of using the phpStorm debugger to show the webpage on localhost:6503 rather than using Apache's localhost. By switching to using Apache instead, it fixed the strange POST data issue.

Comment: Sorry for my bad wording, not sure how else to describe it in a more technically accurate way :)