# Pass Data by AJAX to Controller in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass data to controller for further processing but I get null in controller, however debug of js (ajax) shows the number anyway. What might be the problem?

Ajax:

```
 $('.toggler_btn').on('click', function (event)
            {
                var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
                    if ($(this).text() === '+') {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/List/GetSubItems",
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "html",
                            dataType: "text",
                            data: '{"id":"' + id + '"}', // here it show the data, like 5 or some other number
                            success: function (data)
                            {
                                $('.element_wrapper [data-id="' + id + '"]').html(data);
                            }
                            })
                        $(this).html('-');
                    }
                    else $(this).html('+');
            });
```

Controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetSubItems(string id) // here I get null
    {
        int pID = 0;
        int.TryParse(id, out pID);
        List<H_Table> list = new List<H_Table>();

        foreach (var item in db_connection.H_Table.Where(i => i.PARENT_ID == pID))
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }
        return PartialView(list);
    }
```

Comment: Delete `contentType: "html",` and use just `data: { id: id }`

Comment: contentType : datatype to send to server where as dataType return datatype of data from sever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.toggler_btn').on('click', function (event) {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    if ($(this).text() === '+') {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/List/GetSubItems',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: '{"id":"' + id + '"}',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                $('.element_wrapper [data-id="' + id + '"]').html(data);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("responseText=" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + "\n textStatus=" + textStatus + "\n errorThrown=" + errorThrown);
            }
        });
        $(this).html('-');
    }
    else $(this).html('+');
});
```

Use this one just copy and paste

Comment: This will throw a `500 Internal Server Error` - the method returns html, not json.

Comment: @StephenMuecke are you getting the value of 'id' in controller ?
can you please tell me what you want to do excatly

Comment: It needs to be `dataType: "html",` because the method returns html (and it can simply be `data: { id: id }` and delete the `contentType` option)

Answer (score 0):

Change your content type to "text" and change the data as well.

Comment: I don't need a json, I just need to pass the data to form list and pass it to partial view. Json is not necessary

Comment: Then change your content type to "text". Updated the answer according to your comment

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX request has set `contentType: "html"` but you are actually sending JSON (with `data: '{"id":"' + id + '"}'`). And your controller is receiving a `string`.

So either change your AJAX call to send a raw string:

```
contentType: "text",
data: { id: id }
```

...or update your controller to receive JSON. This latter can be achieved by creating something like this:

```
public ActionResult GetSubItems(ViewModel model)

public class ViewModel {
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**: also, for reference, you might want to see the [difference between `contentType` and `dataType`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322984/differences-between-contenttype-and-datatype-in-jquery-ajax-function/32029658#32029658).

Answer (score 0):

Change data type to "application/json" and  data to this :

```
   data :{
          id : id
   }
```