# AJAX Javascript object to PHP not working

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am trying to grab information from a form and AJAX it to a PHP file that saves it to a csv file, but for some reason, the php file is receiving the Javascript object with empty fields, even though they appear filled in the console

Here is how my code looks like:

```
var contact_info_list = {company_name: "", contact_name: "", email: "", phone: ""};
```

contact_info_list gets populated as the user interacts with the form, then I send it using

```
$.ajax({
url: 'grab_contact_info.php',
type: 'POST',
data: JSON.stringify(contact_info_list),
dataType: 'json'
})
```

And then here is my php code where I grab that object

```
$contact_info = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Can someone please tell me, what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `data: contact_info_list,`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'grab_contact_info.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: contact_info_list,
    dataType: 'json'
})
```

Comment: I believe `dataType` is for ajax response data type, request data type is set using `contentType`

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322984/differences-between-contenttype-and-datatype-in-jquery-ajax-function#14323012 for explanation

Answer (score 0):

You don't neet "JSON.stringify" as you already tell ajax it's a json file. So here is what works for me:

```
var contact_info_list = {company_name: "Test Co.", contact_name: "Jon Doe", email: "jondoe@test.com", phone: "123456789"};

$.ajax({
    url: 'grab_contact_info.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: contact_info_list,
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Then in your grab_contact_info.php file, you get the values like this:

```
$company_name = $_POST["company_name"];
$contact_name = $_POST["contact_name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
```